# tinyMCE base64 Image and storing to mySQL database

Tags: tinymce

I am experimenting with tinyMCE and a have a few questions.  Using their image handler which inserts an image into the textarea.  I use echo `$_POST['textarea']` to verify it displays properly on a web page, and it does.

Looking at the HTML code in the browser webconsole, I see the image referenced as:  `<img title="IMG_1908.JPG" src="data:iamge/jpeg;base64,/9j/4s/...>`

A few questions:

1. Is this image reference actually a base64 image and not just a reference link?  How can I see this?
2. Where does this image "file" actually reside?
3. If I just saved the data represented by $_POST['textarea'] into a database field, would it capture the entire contents in the database so I can just retrieve it and echo it?  Should it be a BLOB field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

1. The firefox web console is a little misleading as it truncates the actual Base64 data, making it look like a short reference link, when in fact, it is typically super long showing all the base64 data characters.
2. Looking at the web browser's page source actually shows the base64 image in it.
3. Yes, the tinyMCE HTML form textbox named as 'textarea' can be saved using the $_POST['textarea'] global variable, into a mySQL BLOB field, then can retrieve the same field and echo it to display it again.  The echo shows the exact same format that was seen in tinyMCE during input.